# Why is there a blue border around focused textboxes now?

Tags: support, design, focus

I noticed that in all Stack Exchange sites, when I focus any textbox, there is now a very visible blue border/outline around it.

Was this outline intentionally added, and if so, what is its purpose?

Examples include:

- [Users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users)
- [Tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags)
- [Search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search)

The provided screenshot illustrates these occurrences across the mentioned areas.

> [image: Combined screenshot]

Comment: Is this causing your problems? If so, can you elaborate on them? (This is one of the accessibility things I _didn't_ think was a trade-off, so it'd be nice to know if it is.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The highlight appears only when the field is focused. This, by itself, seems to be by design. Focused fields are usually highlighted to inform the user what is currently active. This is just regular good UX as well as help with accessibility.

With that said, on 2024-02-15 in recent inquiry for changes on the site [Piper](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/355481/piper) [posted on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428146):

> [...]  The focus state changed for accessibility purposes.

**For more details on the new focus state, see [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/398704/new-focus-styles-updates-styling-for-button-groups)**

Comment: Why CW? You spent time on writing this answer, it's helpful, you deserve the reputation.

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Maybe somebody wants to add more information. I don't really feel I'm owed that much.