# New Focus Styles & Updated Styling for Button Groups

Tags: discussion, featured, design, accessibility, focus

### New Focus Styles

We’ve released a design update to focus styles across the many components within our design system and as well as a new design for our button group component. **See more details on how we approach accessibility in our [Stacks documentation](https://stackoverflow.design/product/foundation/accessibility/)**.

#### Why are we updating the focus style?

Prior to these recent changes, we would commonly apply a custom focus ring around elements to indicate an element was focused. There were several issues with this approach. For one, this focus ring was usually well below the 3:1 contrast ratio needed to meet [WCAG (Level AA) standards](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG22/Understanding/non-text-contrast.html). Also, the focus ring was always rendered as a ring outside of the focused element, meaning it would often be obscured when it exceeded the boundaries of its parent element. Additionally, we often set `outline: none` on elements that have this custom focus ring so an outline would not clash with our custom style, and since OS-level forced color modes often rely on applying an outline to indicate focus, our explicit removal of any outline meant that these force color modes would not indicate that an element was focused.

#### How are we making updates to the focus style?

Our new focus styles address these issues by applying two rings in the form of a contrasting outline and box shadow, one nested inside the other, to ensure focus is clearly indicated. The inner ring matches the page background color, while the outer ring is set to `theme-secondary-400` (which is usually blue). With some exceptions for components with limited interior space, we place these new focus rings inside the bounds of the component. This prevents the focus from being obscured when it may otherwise exceed the boundaries of its parent element. And because the focus style includes an outline, OS-level forced color modes can reappropriate this style to apply focus styles per the user’s preferences.

##### Utility focus classes

In order to help our UI developers apply our new focus styles to components not within the Stacks library, we’ve added [utility focus classes](https://stackoverflow.design/product/base/interactivity/#focus) so we can apply the same focus styles across our products as needed.

#### Current status

Updates to focus styles for many components (see below for a list) have been deployed. On an ongoing basis, we’re updating the focus styles to many custom components across our UIs. Later, we’ll apply our new custom focus style to components that have never included custom focus styles, such as avatars, cards, and links.

#### What we’re looking for

Please report any bugs you find as an answer below this post. Automated tests can only catch so much when it comes to accessibility bugs, so we rely on a mixture of automated and manual testing to give us confidence in our work. There’s always a decent chance we missed a bug or neglected to consider all circumstances that are impacted by these changes, so we appreciate your feedback and enjoy hearing about your experience with these changes.

#### Sample screenshots

##### Block link

[image: Block link in focus with blue outline]

##### Button

[image: 3 button variations in focus with outlines]

##### Button group

[image: 3 buttons within a button group, the first in focus]

##### Form elements

*Radio, checkbox*

[image: Radio button and Checkbox in focus with blue outlines]

*Input (text)*

[image: Input field in focus with blue outline]

*Select*

[image: Select in focus with blue outline]

*Textarea*

[image: Textarea in focus with blue outline]

##### Navigation

*Selected item*

[image: Selected navigation item in focus with blue outline]

*Unselected item*

[image: Unselected navigation item in focus with blue outline]

##### Pagination

*Selected item*

[image: Selected pagination button in focus with blue outline]

*Unselected item*

[image: Unselected pagination button in focus with blue outline]

##### Tag

[image: Tag in focus with blue outline]

##### Toggle switch

*Single*

[image: Single toggle switch in focus with blue outline]

*Multiple*

[image: Multiple toggle switch, the 3rd option in focus with blue outline]

##### Top bar

[image: Top bar with the inbox icon in focus with blue outline]

---

### Accessibility: new button group style

We’ve also released a design update to the button group component. This change will be applied across all Stack Exchange sites.

##### Before

[image: Button group before the change showing 1 button in focus and 1 button selected]

##### After

[image: New button group after the change showing 1 button in focus and 1 button selected]

#### Why are we updating the button group component?

Our original active state did not meet accessibility standards for WCAG AA. The background color used as a visual cue to differentiate between the active and inactive states did not meet the 3:1 contrast needed to meet [WCAG (Level AA) standards](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG22/Understanding/non-text-contrast.html).  Although we explored alternate color options (with higher contrast), we decided to bold the text in addition to the background color change when a button has been selected (is active). Changing the background color created additional complications and inconsistencies with other components and theming. If the link is a different color **and** bold, it no longer fails because the boldness is not color dependent. Using bold as an active state is also consistent with our navigation items.

Additionally, we removed the inner border lines as a tiny step towards our [design vision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392048/our-design-vision-for-stack-overflow-and-the-stack-exchange-network) — yes, we’re still thinking about that and hoping to sneak in some improvements whenever possible. Although it may feel small, removing unnecessary lines helps reduce the overall noise on a page and deemphasizes the button group from other components that deserve more attention.

#### How are we making updates to the button group component?

In order to bold the selected button while avoiding layout shift, we added a bolded hidden pseudo-element containing the button text within each button (See [this CSS Tricks post](https://css-tricks.com/bold-on-hover-without-the-layout-shift/#twitter-widget-0) for a broad overview of this approach). The pseudo-element is populated by the value of a `data-text` attribute on a wrapper around each button’s text. This results in each button’s width being equivalent to its selected state even when it’s not selected.

Check out the [Stacks library pull request](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/pull/1630) for the changes made to our design system and [the Stacks docs](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/button-groups/) to see the new button group design in action.

#### What we’re looking for

With the new focus state style, we needed to add additional padding so that the smallest size of the button group component would display the focus ring accurately. This does increase the overall size of the button group. If you see any issues with wrapping or any bugs related to the button group, please post an answer below this post.

Comment: *"removing unnecessary lines helps reduce the overall noise on a page and deemphasizes the button group from other components that deserve more attention."* The extra space this introduces between the tabs and the border of the entire component does the opposite of deemphasizing the button group. It now has a permanent outline as opposed to just a border.

Comment: For those who are wondering how to test this new style: on any page of this site, even the page you are reading right now, just press the TAB key on your keyboard and the focus will shift to the next element. Pressing it many times will cycle through the elements of the entire page. I suppose most of those who are interested in trying out the new style already knew how to do it, but still, sharing this won't hurt!

Comment: Great to see you are working on accessibility issues.  Thank you!

Comment: Was the [double Search icon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/398680/) a consequence of this change?

Comment: Is this why there's a **POP-UP** asking me to follow stuff? Kinda lost my focus after that.

Answer (score 26):

Thank you!

This is an appreciated change, and a good step in the right direction; always good to see some accessibility work being done.

With that said: **What are useful bug reports in the current state of this project?**

Do you want us to maintain a list of UI elements that don't have an updated focus, particularly elements that have been troublesome in [the past](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340223/294691)? What's in scope of this project - I assume [chat is out of the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/318866/294691), but what about, for instance, [the stackexchange.com domain](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/393974/294691)? Moderator tools? Stack Overflow for Teams<sup>1</sup>? Having some kind of information on what to report (or rereport) in this specific context would be useful.

---

<sup>1</sup> I assume Teams is out of scope, particularly since they just declined my bug report about keyboard shortcuts with the stance that they're not officially supported at all in Teams, but you never know...

Comment: For right now, we're mostly looking for any issues that would have come from the direct changes we made. Even though a list of UI elements would be helpful later on, we'd like to make sure what we shipped is working as intended. For this post, only report on the components we mentioned were changed.

Teams will be getting these changes as well, they have their own release schedule we have to wait for.

Answer (score 19):

#### Answer sorting dropdown

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

> [image: Answer sorting dropdown with focus]

The outline comes very close to the *"Sorted By"* label

#### Activity button

[status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)

> [image: Activity button with focus]

The outline is a strange shape

#### Search box

[status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)

The search dropdown doesn't disappear when you tab out of the search field, leaving it overlapping

> [image: Search field focused with dropdown]

> [image: Search field unfocused, dropdown remains]

#### Watch a tag / Add an ignored tag

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

> [image: Watch a tag button with focus shows as an active button]

> [image: Add an ignored tag button with focus shows as an active button]

These buttons should probably stay as their default fill?

(Aside, should it be *"Ignore a tag"* to match *"Watch a tag"*?)

Also applies on the tag page:

> [image: Ignore tag, unfocussed, showing as inactive]

> [image: Ignore tag, focussed, showing as active]

And even in the navigation buttons, it looks different to your screenshot

> [image: Nav button when focused looks almost active]

#### Badges

[status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)

At least on MSO, it's pretty hard to see the outline

> [image: MSO badge focussed showing low contrast with focus outline]

#### Cramped text on profile page

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

> [image: Cramped text on profile page focused]

Looks even more cramped when focused

#### Help Centre Left Nav

[status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)

> [image: Help centre left nav active page focused]

Should the little blue lozenge on the left get an outline?

Comment: I didn't notice this answer when I submitted [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/398738/hide-search-tooltip-when-focus-moves-away-from-search) bug report. But it turns out the search tooltip not going away was [reported a while ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383039/close-search-help-box-on-unfocus).

Comment: Thank you for adding all the screenshots to your post, I'll go through each one in order. For additional details, see the [Stacks documentation](https://stackoverflow.design/product/foundation/accessibility/).  **Answer sorting dropdown**: dropdowns, selects and input fields all have the focus ring on the outside. Because of this, some closeness will occur with other elements. **Activity button**: this was not a component we were able to update in this first round, this is unchanged. **Search box**: this was unchanged as well but I'll see if I can prioritize this older bug.

Comment: **Watch a tag / Add an ignored tag and navigation buttons**: This is by design, see the documentation for details on why we took this approach. **Badges**: this was not a component we were able to update in this first round, this is unchanged. **Cramped text on profile page**: The smallest button group size does get pretty tight for focus but it's similar to just having an outline around text links (by design). **Help Centre Left Nav**: having the lozenge outlined was not intentional, I'll report the issue but it's likely to be marked as low priority.

Comment: @Carog Thanks!!

Comment: @Carog - I will say, I understand that you want the focus to be obvious, but I think it just looks too much like an active option / primary button. I know you have limited colours now, but it would be good if you could try some iterations?

Answer (score 13):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The [Active]/[Pending approval] button group in the [Tag Synonyms list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) is too wide, and also has the “Pending approval” label duplicated:

[image]

Comment: To be honest: I do not know if this is an issue with the new button group styling or if the problem existed before. Is there any way to switch between old and new styling?

Comment: Well there's the Wayback Machine, and based on [the latest snapshot from last November](https://web.archive.org/web/20231127163012/https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms), the tabs in that page are new, but can't know when they have been added. Anyway the bug is in the tabs, they're not defined correctly.

Comment: Eeeeek! I'll have the team confirm but it seems we may have added a button group to that page accidentally or it's width is off. I've forwarded the issue to the team, thanks for reporting.

Answer (score 7):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)[localization](/questions/tagged/localization)

On site with English interface new design for tabs looks fine even on narrow screens:

> [image]

But on other sites, e.g. [StackOverflow in Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/), the border around tabs looks weird:

> [image]

As well as on [StackOverflow in Spanish](https://es.stackoverflow.com/):

> [image]

I'm not sure about original intentions here but I think that the border expected to be around tabs without so large empty area. It looks elegant only when all buttons fit into single row.

Additional links with "broken" tab design (observable even on screens regular aspect ratio, tested on iPad Pro 11"):

- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/hot
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/hot
- https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/hot

Comment: I even experience this on the English sites, on a phone with a narrow screen (Sony Xperia 10 V).

Comment: Was it stacking like this before the new design? I simulated the behavior on the old design using [this wayback machine link](https://web.archive.org/web/20240101052520/https://meta.stackexchange.com/) and it looks like the previous behavior on narrow screens was also funky: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIqSw.png (the corners are squared on right side of the first row). Actually I would say this is at least better than the former behavior.

Answer (score 5):

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

The checkbox and radio box look very similar and could easily be mistaken, could they have a clearer distinction between them? You also haven't shown what they look like when selected?

[image]

Comment: We're assuming the likelihood of this mistake happening should be fairly low because radio buttons will always come in a list of 2 or more. In those cases, you would be able to see the unfocused radio option as well. Additionally, these two components _should_ never appear side by side like this in product (this was just for displaying the change in the meta post). You can see an example of all the states (included selected) without our [Stacks Guidelines](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/checkbox/#base-style).

Answer (score 5):

[status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)

The ["Migrated" tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=migrated&daterange=last30days) alone in the ["Tools" menu](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) is still using the old Button Group style.

The other tabs "Stats", "Close" and "Delete" tabs are applied with new Button Group style.

**"Stats" tab screenshot:**

[image: Tools - Stats tab]

**"Tools" tab screenshot:**

[image: Tools - Migrated tab]

**GIF for the same:**

[image: Migrated Tab style issue]

Answer (score 5):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

On one’s profile page, the *Select your next badge* popup has buttons to choose to display either *Available*, *All*, *Gold*, *Silver*, or *Bronze*:

[image: The Select your next badge popup with Silver selected, but gold and bronze badges still being displayed.]

These buttons don’t seem to work anymore.

Answer (score 4):

[status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro)

### Font size in the button group component as used on the sites has decreased; please increase it to match the old size

I noticed that the font size in the button group (tabs) component has gotten smaller than it used to be, especially in user profile pages when going through subtabs of activity subpages.

I find this smaller size less accessible. Can the size please be bumped up to match what it used to be?

Comment: The font size did not changed as part of this update. All font sizes were kept the same. The sorting and filtering buttons on the profile page have a font size of 11px (before and now). You can [see an example](https://web.archive.org/web/20240218021504/https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/377214/sonic-the-anonymous-hedgehog) on the profile page (next to "Top posts" section) of the old button using the wayback machine with a font size of 11px. The new style is still using 11px.

Comment: @Carog I'm not talking about those buttons there. I'm talking about the subtabs of activity pages, i.e., in https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/377214/sonic-the-anonymous-hedgehog?tab=activity. The buttons to filter to specific types of actions are a lot smaller than before.

Comment: All the filter buttons in within the profile pages (including the substabs of activity) use the same size for consistency — `s-btn__xs` is and has been applied to those buttons for a while (possibly since the last time we made a change to the profile page design). I can't get a wayback link since it's harder to get a specific tab that's been captured but you can still see the old buttons on those subtabs within an instance of Teams. Teams hasn't gotten the update yet but they share the same styles for those sub pages.

Comment: @Carog Ah, yes, I see. The reduced gray color along the top and bottom edges made the text appear perceptibly smaller when it wasn't actually so.

Answer (score 3):

[status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)

### Very high or low scores cause strange issues

Tl;dr - when the score takes up a lot of horizontal space, the voting circle outlines aren't circles anymore. Can this be fixed? This is easiest to see on scores with five non-comma chars (i.e., negative four-digit scores / positive five-digit ones). That said, it's also visible if you look closely at a four-digit score that's positive.

##### Example #1 (high score, Stack Overflow)

[Stretched voting buttons in a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841333/why-is-subtracting-these-two-epoch-milli-times-in-year-1927-giving-a-strange-r)

[image]

Looking at [the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20240224104733/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841333/why-is-subtracting-these-two-epoch-milli-times-in-year-1927-giving-a-strange-r), these buttons used to be circular. Not exactly sure *why* this happens, but... they should probably still be round even with a score of over 10,000

##### Example #2 (low score, Meta Stack Exchange)

[image]

I didn't check the Wayback Machine, but I'd assume it's the same root cause.

Answer (score 2):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

#### Hover state background for button groups too light

There is a hover state for each button in the button group. But there is not enough contrast between the hover state background and the page background. So the hover state is barely visible.

For example, in this image, my cursor is hovering over the "Bugs" button.
[image: Button group with hover state for first button]

#### Hover state background overrides focus state background

Note this might be directly caused by the above issue.

When you tab into a button, a dark gray background is applied to it.
[image: button with dark gray active state background]

However if your cursor happens to also be hovering over the button, the above mentioned hover state background overrides the dark gray background, causing it to look like there is no background applied at all because of the presence of the stronger blue outline. See following image:
[image: button with active state and hover state background]

This will probably be fixed if a darker background is used for the hover state. Or perhaps the hover state background should not be applied on focus-state buttons.