# Hide search tooltip when focus moves away from search

Tags: bug, search, top-bar, accessibility

I wanted to test out the [new focus styles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/398704/new-focus-styles-updated-styling-for-button-groups) using the guidance on [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/398704/new-focus-styles-updated-styling-for-button-groups#comment1330990_398704). When I tabbed into the search box, the tooltip showing how to search popped up, which is fine. But when I tabbed out of the search box (and search tooltip), the tooltip remained opened (see screenshot below). I think the tooltip should go away after tabbing away from search since it blocks your view.

[image: search tooltip remains open after tabbing out]

Comment: Couldn't decide between feature-request or bug, went with bug. Also not sure if this has been reported before. I did a quick search but couldn't find anything.

Comment: It goes away when clicking anywhere outside, which I think is the expected behavior. Do you have example of such a popup that close when just tabbing out, without mouse click? (Or touch screen tap.)

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda Sure, the vote buttons and other icons below it (for the vote buttons you have to focus on it for a second for the tooltip to appear). I think for accessibility purposes they should close when tabbing out.